# Using Java script to sort HTML table by appropriate column on column header click

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I am trying to set up a HTML table that when you click on the column header it will sort the table by that column. My current solution works perfectly for the first column, its something I found on W3schools.

**Edit: (Issue was the script comparing all the contained HTML in each TD, not just the displayed text)**

But when I tried to generalise it with "n" instead of leaving a number in the java script for which column to sort, I can't seem to get it to take the correct value for n.

My plan was to use the code from W3schools (below) for sorting the first column, but insert a variable n to allow the same piece of code to sort multiple columns. I am trying to get the Java script to read n from the HTML section itself but i am not sure why it's not working.

This is my version of the W3schools code where I have tried to use n, this currently sorts the first column no matter which column header I click on.

```js
function sortTable(n) {
 var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
 table = document.getElementById("mytable");
 switching = true;
 dir = "asc";
 while (switching) {
  switching = false;
  rows = table.rows;
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
   shouldSwitch = false;
   x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
   y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
   if (dir == "asc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() > y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
     shouldSwitch = true;
     break;
    }
   } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() < y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
     shouldSwitch = true;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
   rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
   switching = true;
   switchcount ++; 
  } else {
   if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
    dir = "desc";
    switching = true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
   <tr>
    <th>
     <div onclick="sortTable(0)">a</div>
    </th>
    <th>
     <div onclick="sortTable(1)">b</div>
    </th>
    <th>
     <div onclick="sortTable(2)">c</div>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>04718J00065</td>
    <td>2100305513</td>
    <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>29417J01131</td>
    <td>2100305513</td>
    <td>30</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>07416J01979</td>
    <td>2100029648</td>
    <td>0</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I think what the issue is, is that the Java script isn't getting a value for n and it's defaulting to 0 which is why it sorts the first column no matter which header was clicked on. How can I get it to read n=0 from `onclick="sortTable(0)"`, n=1 from `onclick="sortTable(1)"` etc?

Comment: have you had a look at datatable plugin? does exactly what you want.

Comment: btw the code you posted works fine here

Comment: Running the code snippet I see this is working, on my local copy I have separate files containing the Java script and HTML with the HTML pointing to the Java script file at the start. Could this be why it's not working for me?

Comment: no, that is not the issue if you load the js at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag. That's because that javascript (not java script) is immediately executed when loaded and if you do it before the table is rendered it will never work

Comment: I currently have
<script src="../java/Java.js"></script>
in the head of the page before the body. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: yes it is. but note: javascript is not java. they are not the same.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will have another look through and see if i can find the cause.

Comment: just put `<script src="../java/Java.js"></script>` immediately before `</body>` and it will work

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue, it is still only sorting by the first column (n=0) no matter which table header I click on. I will go through step by step to rebuild what I have and see if i can spot what causes it not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what was causing the issue.

Using

```
(x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() > y.innerHTML.toUpperCase())
```

and

```
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
```

compares everything inside that TD, not just the text that gets displayed. I had removed a `<a></a>` section from each TD when posting the code for this question trying to avoid posting code in too much detail and the link was pointing to files that shared a name with the string that was in the first column.

```
<table id="mytable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div onclick="sortTable(0)">a</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div onclick="sortTable(1)">b</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div onclick="sortTable(2)">c</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="04718J00065.html">04718J00065</a></td>
                <td><a href="04718J00065.html">2100305513</a></td>
                <td><a href="04718J00065.html">10</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="29417J01131.html">29417J01131</a></td>
                <td><a href="29417J01131.html">2100305513</a></td>
                <td><a href="29417J01131.html">30</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="07416J01979.html">07416J01979</a></td>
                <td><a href="07416J01979.html">2100029648</a></td>
                <td><a href="07416J01979.html">0</a></td>
            </tr>
</table>

<script>
function sortTable(n) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("A")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("A")[n];
            if (dir == "asc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() > y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toUpperCase() < y.innerHTML.toUpperCase()) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount ++; 
        } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

My solution to this was just to swap "TD" in the script to "A" so it would compare inside the  tag and not the link location itself. My changes to include "n" had worked as intended.